# Is there a way to define model fields in function?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

The normal way to define a model is as follows:

```js
Ext.define('App.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Is there a way to specify the fields (and perhaps all the config properties) inside an init-type method, similar to how a component's config can be set in initComponent()?

It would be useful to have this capability in order to do things like set local vars for certain repetitive properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function anywhere you want in Javascript!

```
Ext.define('App.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: function() {
        return [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
        ];
    }() // important: run it immediately!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this in initComponent.  I use this sometimes when creating stores within a component passing in a variable based on whether or not I want the store to autoLoad.

```
Ext.define('App.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    initFields: function(fieldType) {
        return [
            {name: 'id', type: fieldType},
            {name: 'name', type: fieldType}
        ];
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(me, {
            fields: me.initFields('string')
        });
        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: Models are not component, so the `initComponent` would never get called. Furthermore, model fields are a static property, that is all instances of a given model class must share the same fields. You really shouldn't override that at the instance level.

Comment: You are completely right on initComponent.  I was just giving an example based on another way this could be done.  The example I was giving doesn't override any statics.  All initFields() does is set some properties as per the fields array.  Yes, it is inside initComponent, but if you are extending a class that you don't want certain things to be able to be changed i.e. fields, then overriding at instance level is fine.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is overriding any statics provided on an instance this way.  But what is the point of extending a Model class if you're just going to override the fields anyway? If you really wanted you could pass this.fields to initFields() and execute some code on the fields and return them and then set fields to i.e. fields: me.initFields(this.fields), then no statics would ever be completely ignored.